# PHP - remove <img> tag from string

Tags: php, string

Hey, I need to delete all images from a string and I just can't find the right way to do it.

Here is what I tryed, but it doesn't work:

```
preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content);
echo $content;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $content = preg_replace(..., $content);

Comment: you can use https://txt2re.com/ to formulate regular expression. Usually, I use this one and after that, modify the code as per my need.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Try dropping the `\` in front of the `>`.

Edit: I just tested your regex and it works fine.  This is what I used:

```
<?
    $content = "this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content); 
    echo $content;
?>
```

The result is:

```
this is something with an (image)  in it.
```

Comment: Can you make this except of (image) it will replace with the alt of an image?

Comment: Try dropping the \ in front of the >. `preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content);` Hows that's different from the actual question?

Answer (score 23):

You need to assign the result back to `$content` as `preg_replace` does not modify the original string.

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content);
```

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using the [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) method.

Comment: This strips **all** tags, not only img tags.

Answer (score 8):

Sean it works fine i've just used this code

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content); 
echo $content;
```

//the result it's only the plain text. It works!!!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to display the first 300 words of a news story as a preview which unfortunately meant that if a story had an image within the first 300 words then it was displayed in the list of previews which really messed with my layout. I used the above code to hide all of the images from the string taken from my database and it works wonderfully!

```
$news = $row_latest_news ['content'];
$news = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $news); 
if (strlen($news) > 300){
echo substr($news, 0, strpos($news,' ',300)).'...';
} 
else { 
echo $news; 
}
```

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name:

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->load->helper('security');
$h=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_image_tags($comment));
```

If user inputs

```
<img src="#">
```

In the database table just insert character this #

Works for me

Answer (score -4):

simply use the form_validation class of codeigniter:

```
strip_image_tags($str).

$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre_campo', 'label', 'strip_image_tags');
```

Comment: Did he say, he is using CodeIgniter?