# extracting image tag from a html code in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch my articles and I need to make a slider out of them.

Each of my articles has an image inside it's text, like this:

```
<p>
<img src="story_img.jpg" width=120 height=80>
In the last couple of weeks I often had to download a lot of files, submitted to a web-based teaching platform. Downloading all these files by hand is very annoying so I implemented a short Groovy script. Since Groovy has a great support for parsing well-formed XML-like information it fails if you want to parse unstructured and nasty HTML code.
</p>
```

Now what I need is simple, first I should parse the image and then remove it from the text .

So that I could have 2 constants

```
$imgOfText = ?

$TextWithOutImg = ?
```

I tried different ways in php and [even read this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

But I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's HTML so you can parse it ! [Use DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) !

```
$html = '<p>';
$html.= '<img src="story_img.jpg" width=120 height=80>';
$html.= 'In the last couple of weeks I often had to download a lot ';
$html.= 'of files, submitted to a web-based teaching platform. Downloading ';
$html.= 'all these files by hand is very annoying so I implemented a short ';
$html.= 'Groovy script. Since Groovy has a great support for parsing well-';
$html.= 'formed XML-like information it fails if you want to parse ';
$html.= 'unstructured and nasty HTML code.';
$html.= '</p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$imgOfText = $img->getAttribute('src');
$TextWithOutImg = $p->nodeValue;
```

[Demo here](http://codepad.org/eOa1ygpm)

Comment: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object  this is what i get when i run the script . i saw the demo and its working there but not for me

Comment: @Mac Taylor : Did you copy/paste the demo on your server or did you change something (for example, the HTML)? If so, can you tell me what change you did ?

Comment: i think its not working when im using it in a while loop  e.g. :   while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
 $html = $row["content"];

Comment: @Mac Taylor : maybe you should display what $row['content'] contains. It may be escaped / bad encoded

Answer (score 2):

How about this [Live Demo](http://codepad.org/oAP5BqSm) I whipped up. It's just some very basic parsing using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Im sure this could be done with regular expressions, but I never was any good at that :)

**CODE**

```
<?php

    $html = '<p>';
    $html.= '    <img src="story_img.jpg" width=120 height=80>';
    $html.= '    In the last couple of weeks I often had to download a lot ';
    $html.= 'of files, submitted to a web-based teaching platform. Downloading ';
    $html.= 'all these files by hand is very annoying so I implemented a short ';
    $html.= 'Groovy script. Since Groovy has a great support for parsing well-';
    $html.= 'formed XML-like information it fails if you want to parse ';
    $html.= 'unstructured and nasty HTML code.';
    $html.= '</p>';

    $spot = strpos($html, 'src="', strpos($html, '<img'))+5;
    $spot2 =strpos($html, '"', $spot);
    $imgOfText = substr($html, $spot, $spot2-$spot);

    $spot = strpos($html, '<img');
    $spot2 = strpos($html, '>', $spot)+1;
    $TextWithOutImg = substr($html,0,$spot).substr($html,$spot2);

    echo "Image Source: ".$imgOfText."\n\n";
    echo "Text Without Image:\n".$TextWithOutImg;

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Image Source: story_img.jpg
>
> Text Without Image:
>
> <p>In the last
>   couple of weeks I often had to
>   download a lot of files, submitted to
>   a web-based teaching platform.
>   Downloading all these files by hand is
>   very annoying so I implemented a short
>   Groovy script. Since Groovy has a
>   great support for parsing well-formed
>   XML-like information it fails if you
>   want to parse unstructured and nasty
>   HTML code.</p>

Comment: What if, one day, he finally closes his `<img/>` tag ? :)

Comment: @Capsule & @Mac Taylor : What if you use `>` in your text? What if your image is embedded like this : `<img src=story_img.jpg width="120" height="80" />`? etc...etc... You should use regex or regex shortcut to find things in HTML.

Comment: @Shikiryu: You can use `>` in the text with no problem as the code is looking for the first `>` after `<img`. If you come up with a false hit on this, there is a larger problem with your code. I will agree that regex is a faster, better, neater solution though.

Comment: @Dutchie432 : I don't see any problem with my code since DomDocument takes `<img/>` and `<img>` and I meant *shouldn't*. You don't use regex for HTML. Your solution is better than regex but it assumes a lot of thing which could go wrong. (ie : `<p>text<img ...` text will be ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Try this topic: [PHP - remove <img> tag from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of PHP libraries that can parse HTML, even invalid one.

[PHPQuery](http://phpquery-library.blogspot.com/)

[Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

[Zend DOM Query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.dom.query.html)

Here is a PHPQuery example that prints all img tags appear on StackOverflow home page.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');

include('phpQuery.php');

$pq = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html, 'utf-8');

foreach ($pq->find('img') as $img)
{
    echo pq($img)->attr('src') .'<br>';

}

?>
```

Another example that extracts text of all paragraphs:

```
foreach ($pq->find('p') as $p)
{
    echo pq($p)->text() .'<br>';

}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, why importing a library to extract it when a _native_ (almost) one can do it? That's laziness, like using jQuery to get an element id.

Comment: Shikiryu, if you need to parse HTML that is not well formed you are out of luck while these libraries can do that

Comment: Well, that isn't true. DOMDocument can parse malformed HTML, that's why it is powerful. Those libraries only got the advantage of being nicer to read and simpler to use for me.