# remove image tag from string and replace with string

Tags: php, string, replace, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - remove <img> tag from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string)

I need to remove an image tag from a string and at the same time replace it with something. Here is what I have:

```
$body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p>
<p><img class="news" id="" src="images/news_48.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>Curabitur tincidunt vehicula mauris, nec facilisis nisl ultrices sit amet:</p>
<p><img class="gallery" id="26" src="images/gallery_48.png" alt="" /></p>
<p><img id="this_image_must_stay" src="images/some_image.png" alt="" /></p>';
```

I need to do one thing if the image has class="news" and another thing if it's class="gallery". I'm thinking some pseudocode like:

```
<?php
  if(news){
      replace the image tag where class=news with %%news%%
  }
  if(gallery){
      replace the image tag where class=gallery with %%gallery%%
      assign the value 26 to some variable
  }
?>
```

So now `$body` would contain:

```
$body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p>
<p>%%news%%</p>
<p>Curabitur tincidunt vehicula mauris, nec facilisis nisl ultrices sit amet:</p>
<p>%%gallery%%</p>
<p><img id="this_image_must_stay" src="images/some_image.png" alt="" /></p>';
```

I guess I have to use preg_match/replace, but I'm not good at regex. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every time you use a regex on html, a kitten gets stomped on.

Comment: @MarkB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags This is one of (if not) the most popular answers on this website.

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p>
<p><img class="news" id="" src="images/news_48.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>Curabitur tincidunt vehicula mauris, nec facilisis nisl ultrices sit amet:</p>
<p><img class="gallery" id="26" src="images/gallery_48.png" alt="" /></p>
<p><img id="this_image_must_stay" src="images/some_image.png" alt="" /></p>';

if (preg_match('{.*<img class="gallery".*}', $body)) {
    $some_variable = 26;
}

print preg_replace('{<img class="(news|gallery)".*/>}', '%%\\1%%', $body);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up with this. It kind of works :)

```
<?php
    $str = preg_replace('/<img class="news"[^>]+\>/i', "%%news%%", $str);
    preg_match('/<img class="gallery" id="(.*?)"[^>]+\>/i', $str, $id);
    $id = $id[1];
    $str = preg_replace('/<img class="gallery"[^>]+\>/i', "%%gallery%%", $str);
    echo $str;
?>
```

But then I thought about, what if I have two or more gallery images and want to fetch their ids' too. A %%gallery%% would have to be linked to it's respective id, for each %%gallery%%, in some way.