# Remove </div> HTML tag from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

According to the post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string), the code below can remove the HTML tag, such as `<div>`. But I found that the end tag `</div>` still remain in the string.

```
$content = "<div id=\"header\">this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.</div>";
$content = preg_replace("/<div[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); 
echo $content;
```

I have tried something below, but still not work, how can I fix this issue?

```
$content = preg_replace("/<\/div[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); 
$content = preg_replace("/<(/)div[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The end tag doesn't have anything between the div and the `>`, so instead try something like:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<\/?div[^>]*\>/i", "", $content);
```

This will remove patterns of the form:

```
<div>
</div>
<div class=...>
```

Comment: +1 it works, what is the meaning of `?` inside `/<\/?div[^>]*\>/i`

Comment: the ? means that the / that comes before it - is optional, that's why it matches both <div> and </div>

Answer (score 3):

change it to `"/<[\/]*div[^>]*>/i"`

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee the HTML being passed in will be valid and structured in a certain way you should be OK with regex.

In general, though, it's best to avoid using regex for working with HTML, because the markup can be so varied and messy. Instead, try using a library like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) - it handles all the messiness for you.

With DOMDocument you would do something like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$headerElement = $doc->getElementById('header');
$headerElement->parentNode->removeChild($headerElement);
$amendedHtml = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = preg_replace("/<\/?(div|b|span)[^>]*\>/i", "", $content);
```

remove all

```
<div...>
</div>
<b....>
</b>
<span...>
</span>
```