# Remove 'img' tag from string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - remove <img> tag from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string)

I have my content like this:

```
$content = '<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img width="645" height="450" src="/proshore/userfiles/image/1.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p>An explorer adventures into an unknown world, yet it seems that he has been there      before. A short animated film directed by Malcolm Sutherland in 2010. With music by Alison Melville and Ben Grossman, and foley by Leon Lo. Sound design / mix by Malcolm Sutherland.</p>
<p>The animation is all hand-drawn; a mix of drawing / pastels on paper and digital animation with Toonboom Studio and a wacom cintiq tablet, assembled in After Effects 7 and edited in Sony Vegas 8.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>';
```

I want the output ignoring the `<img>` tag. I tried some messups with preg_replace but didn't work.. It will be a great help if someone can explain me how it works.

Comment: What have you tried? HTML/XML-parsing/manipulation via REGEX is normally a bad idea. If the input is even slightly malformed or unpredictable, the pattern will fail. You may want to look into [PHP:DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Can you write what output you want?

Comment: No need to use regular expressions here.  There's an a̶p̶p̶ function for that! ;)  It's called [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not forced to [use regular expressions to parse HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), then I'd suggest using PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function along with its `allowed_tags` argument.

This will tell PHP to remove all the html tags and leave the ones your specified in the `allowed_tags`.

Example usage taken from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) -

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text); 
// output : Test paragraph. Other text

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); 
// output - <p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

So, if you simply specify all the HTML tags in `allow_tags` **except the `<img>` tag**, you should get the results that you need - only removing the `<img>` tag from your string.

Comment: Although this solution will work without problems, but it will leave an unwanted `<p></p>` which is now around the `<img>`, also you don't always know what tags can occur and listing them all omitting just the image - it's just not the best practice..

Comment: The OP did not describe the reason for this functionality - for all we know empty holder tags could be a desired effect.  This answer is based only on the information that was provided.  I agree with you (somewhat) with regard to explicitly specifying *all* HTML tags.. maybe not the best way... but I'm open to suggestions :P

Comment: thanks @zol - for the constructive criticism!

Comment: thanks :) the intention was really constructive, because the solution is perfectly functional and achieves what the OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this regex `<img.+?((/>)|(</img>))` with empty string