# Remove a slash after ?img=

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<html>
<body background="http://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/abstract-background-22.jpg">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<DIV align="center">
<?php
$img = $_GET["img"];
?>
<?php
if($img=="") { echo ""; } else { echo "<img src='" . $img . "' />"; } ?>
<br>
</body></html>
```

I'm using this for screensnapr so when i'm trying to see the picture with `http://imagesnappper.co.cc/Images?img=` it autoamtically adds a `/` after `?img=`
so it's like `http://imagesnappper.co.cc/Images?img=/8kd6lx.jpg` and it won't show the image how to delete that slash?

Comment: because i can't center the image that way

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - remove <img> tag from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using...

```
$img = ltrim($img, "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways, but the simplest and nastiest that comes to mind is [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)():

```
$img=substr($_GET[img], 1);
```