# PHP - replace <img> tags and return src

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Mission is to replace all `<img>` tags in given string with `<div>` tags and `src` property as inner text.
In search for the answer I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string)

```
<?php

    $content = "this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content); 
    echo $content;

?>
```

result:

```
this is something with an (image)  in it.
```

**Question: How to upgrade script ant get this result:**

```
this is something with an <div>test.png</div>  in it.
```

Comment: You don't want to be using regexes to parse HTML.  They are not up to the task.  Your regex solution is extremely fragile.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html explains why.

Answer (score 18):

This is the kind of problem that PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class excels at:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    // put your replacement code here
}

$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: `$img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src_url );`

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = "this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
$content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', '<div>$1</div>', $content); 
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$strings = 'awdaw <img src="http://ua1.us/media/media.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100"> aw <img src="http://ua1.us/media/media1awdwa.jpg"> wawadwad';

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $strings, $images);
foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
    preg_match('/src="([^"]+)/i', $image, $replacements);
    $replacement    = isset($replacements[1]) ? $replacements[1] : (isset($replacements[0]) ? $replacements[0] : "image");    
    $strings    = str_replace($image, $replacement, $strings);
}
echo $strings;
```