# Replace <a /> tag with its src attribute that have another attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

this:

```
$text = '<img class="fruit" src="http://exmple.com/apple.png" id="apple"><BR>
<img class="fruit" src="http://exmple.com/Lemon.png" ><BR>
<img src="http://exmple.com/banana.png" class="fruit"><BR>';

$pattern = '/<img(.*) src="([^"].*)"(.*)\>/i'; //<--the problem
$replace = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $text);
echo $replace;
```

give me:

```
http://exmple.com/apple.png" id="apple
http://exmple.com/lemon.png
http://exmple.com/banana.png" class="fruit
```

All I need just replace them with their `src` value; like this:

```
http://exmple.com/apple.png
http://exmple.com/lemon.png
http://exmple.com/banana.png
```

Got hours on [codepad](http://codepad.org/xijqIEVa), but still have no desired `$pattern`; I got [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783760/php-replace-img-tags-and-return-src) before but didn't work; I'm not good at all on ragex logic, so I need help, please.

Comment: $pattern = '<img\s+src\s*=\s*["'']([^"'']+)["'']\s*/*>'

Let me know if this works..

Comment: Wouldn't a DOM parser like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) be a better solution to scrape the `src`es?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? You want to remove the image tags and replace them with just the src string?

Comment: @HirenPandya got this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` , thanks tough;

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is very brittle, just use a parser, modify the node attribute and output the HTML again.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, but img possibbly have other several attr with unknown position,

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks, I know but I only need the images, another tag will be removed;

Comment: @Charlie That doesn't mean much, you can add remove tags as you wish and the output the HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `.` in your string.

```
// This:
$pattern = '/<img(.*) src="([^"]*)"(.*)\>/i';

// Not this:
$pattern = '/<img(.*) src="([^"].*)"(.*)\>/i';
```

However, rather that doing a weird replace to remove the parts you don't want, I'd consider pulling out the parts you do want and printing them instead.

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src="([^"]*)"/i', $text, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[1]);
```

Comment: @Charlie Glad to help, I'm going to update in 1 sec with another suggestion too.

Comment: Actually I need to reformat an html doc without loosing the image, I need it all to be strings; I will do `strip_tags($doc, '<img>');` and replace the img using the src; thanks again for ur suggest.