# PHP regex replace content in img src attribute?

Tags: php, regex, php-7.4

I'm new to PHP and have following issue. I have to sanitize images and need to replace all `img` src if it starts with `http://` with `/files/images/`.

Is that possible to do with regex?

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783760/php-replace-img-tags-and-return-src) but it does't fulfil everything I need.

Comment: "*It it does't fulfil everything I need.*" - what does it do with your input? What do you expect?

Comment: It could be better to avoid regex (which is expensive) and rather use str_replace() ... but it's hard to tell without an example of what input and output you expect to have

Comment: Regex101 is a good place to try regexes, [here is some start](https://regex101.com/r/rpqImO/1).

Answer (score 0):

A modification of the thread you linked to do what you are requesting:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $current_src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    $new_src = preg_replace('http://', '/files/images', $current_src);
    $img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src );
}

$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

I don't have a machine with PHP readily available to test this for you (not at home), so let me know if you have any issues with it and I would be happy to troubleshoot for you.