# Wordpress the_content() - customizing img template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a blog, that has specific html5 structure for img:

```
<figure>
<img />
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is there a way to customize, how the_content() handles img rendering, adding my own template for img specificly (plus adding the_post_thumbnail_caption() template)?

Or is there a way to make your own template for WYSIWYG. I'm asking because i'd like to allow user, to apply one out of three possible img displays, that are bound to specific class of figure element (for example )

Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you just create your own [[shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)] that generates that format?

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_the_content() and then use preg_match to look for the img tag and replace with your own code see how to replace img that with preg_match here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107203/1287608

and the get_the_content() function here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content