# PHP exclude information from xml

Tags: php, xml

I want to exclude just the `<img>` tag(ads in a newsfeed) from an xml file to be shown at my php file. I know that [these](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) should work to remove attributes but isn't there anything else to **just** remove the img from being shown? I think there has to be another way for this and would like to know what php function is good for this problem? (+ the information in the link doesn't work for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **`Regular Expression`** to simplify things. Pass your **`XML`** content like shown.

```
$filtered_content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $your_xml_content);
```

Comment: This did work thanks. Could use some more explaining for the people visiting later like:
$xmltoecho = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $your_xml_content); 
How to use preg_replace:
preg_replace("What to replace","What replaces it",$your_xml_content);
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regular expression to replace the image tag......or just using the style property you can make the visibility of the image tag to hidden or display to none as it gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107194/php-remove-img-tag-from-string) stack overflow question can be of help. Putting your xml in the `$content` string and regexing just as described in the top answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a DOMDocument, you can [getElementsByTagname](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) then iterate through the list you get to [removeChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)ren. Removing attributes won't do it.

Comment: If you clicked the link I provided, You could see I want it different than this way.

Comment: Well, I did click the link (what's with the assumption!), and my solution _is_ different than "this way", as it would actually work (removeChild is "good for this problem" while removeAttribute is not). You could've clarified what exactly is wrong with "that way", before downvoting a correct solution.

Comment: It's still an even bigger and annoying solution. + you're telling , removing attributes wont do it. Which I just did.